# Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Date' - Typescript not compiling

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I've got the following code for a jquery timer plugin. The compiler gives me the error: "Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Date'"

```
$(function(){
    var note = $('#note'),
        ts = new Date(2012, 0, 1),
        newYear = false;

    if((new Date()) > ts){
        ts = (new Date()).getTime() + 24*60*60*1000; //counting 24 hours
        newYear = false;
    }   

});


        });

    };
```

Comment: In `ts = new Date(2012, 0, 1)`, `ts` is a date, but in `ts = (new Date()).getTime() + 24*60*60*1000;` `ts` is a number. May I suggest you to use momentjs to "play" with date?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to create a new instance of `Date`:

```
if((new Date()) > ts){
    ts = new Date((new Date()).getTime() + 24*60*60*1000);
    newYear = false;
}
```

This way `ts` is assigned with a new `Date` with the given time.
Also, there's no need to create two instance of `Date` for now, you can just put it in a variable an reuse it:

```
$(function(){
    var note = $('#note'),
        ts = new Date(2012, 0, 1),
        newYear = false,
        now = new Date();

    if(now > ts){
        ts = new Date(now.getTime() + 24*60*60*1000);
        newYear = false;
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When assigning variables in typescript it can help to assign the type explicitly to avoid any confusion.
When assigning:
`ts = new Date(2012, 0, 1)`
you avoided declaring what type ts was and left it up to the "compiler".
If you had tried:
`var ts : number = new Date(2012, 0, 1);`
for example (I know this takes up more space, sorry), you would have gotten as similar error.
To get around this, you either need a new variable for your declaration:
`ts = new Date(now.getTime() + 24*60*60*1000);`
Or more cleanly, you avoid declaring ts and construct:
`var note = $('#note')`
after you have decided what types all the values will be. Something like:
`if(new Date() > (new Date(2012, 0, 1))`
and decide from there how your "note" object will be formed.

Answer (score -3):

```
let oneweek = new Date((new Date()).setDate(today.getDate() + 7));
let twoweek = new Date((new Date()).setDate(today.getDate() + 14));
let onemonth = new Date((new Date()).setDate(today.getMonth() + 1));
let threemonth = new Date((new Date()).setDate(today.getMonth() + 3));
```

Comment: When you write answer, don't just put some code. Explain why it works and provide some useful links if needed, so that OP can actually understand the solution.

Comment: Besides what kamyl said, answers should address the issue raised by the OP. The answer here seems to be about how to compute date deltas, but that's not the problem *the OP faced*. The OP's problem is one of type checking, not one of arithmetic.